# Three-term gaussian fit to gaussian data (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, gaussian, data-fitting

I am trying to fit a gaussian data to a specific three-term gaussian  (in which the amplitude in one term is equal to twice the standard deviation of the next term). Here is my attempt:

```
import numpy as np

#from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import scipy.optimize as optimize

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#r=np.linspace(0.0e-15,4e-15, 100) 

data = np.loadtxt('V_lambda_n.dat')
r = data[:, 0]
V = data[:, 1]

def func(x, ps1, ps2, ps3, ps4):
    return ps1*np.exp(-(x/ps2)**2) + ps2*np.exp(-(x/ps3)**2) + ps3*np.exp(-(x/ps4)**2)

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func, r, V, maxfev=10000)

#params = optimize.curve_fit(func, ps1, ps2, ps3, ps4)

#[ps1, ps2, ps2, ps4] = params[0]

p1=plt.plot(r, V, 'bo', label='data')
p2=plt.plot(r, func(r, *popt), 'r-', label='fit')

plt.xticks(np.linspace(0, 4, 9, endpoint=True))
plt.yticks(np.linspace(-50, 150, 9, endpoint=True))
plt.show()
```

Here is the result:

[image]

How may I fix this code to improve the fit? Thanks

Comment: .........popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(partial(func, x, ps1, ps2, ps3, ps4), r, V, maxfev=10000)....?

Comment: Hi @AriGold , when I try that I get the error "NameError: name 'partial' is not defined"

Comment: from functools import partial

Comment: @AriGold I get the errot "NameError: name 'x' is not defined". This is one of the arguments in my fitting function.

Comment: its your task from now, please found the reason.........

Comment: Since this is an optimization problem, I am thinking of trying an initial guess, how may I choose initial guess for ps1, ps2, ps3 and ps4?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of friends from scipy-user forum, I tried as initial guess the following:

p0=[V.max(), std_dev, V.max(), 2]

The fit got a lot better. The new fit is as shown

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjRAH.png)

I hope the fit could get better than this.